# Test results changed for both variables when the condition is set on one variable?

Tags: c++, class, oop

By removing the if statement in the main function, both tickets are available. However when adding the if statement on one condition, both tickets are sold. Any help please? Below are the question and my code:

A theatre sells seats for shows and needs a system to keep track of the seats they have sold tickets for. Define a class for a type called ShowTickets.
The class should contain a collection field for the rows, seat numbers, and whether the tickets have been sold or not. Your class only needs to support 10 sold tickets. Assume a ticket you have not referenced before has a sold status of false.

Include the following member functions:
A function to check if the ticket has been sold with this signature: bool is_sold(string row, string seat);
A function to update the ticket status to sold with this signature:  void sell_seat(string row, string seat);
A function to print the row, seat number, and sold status delimited by a space with this signature: string print_ticket(string row, string seat);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ShowTickets{
public:
    string Row;
    string Seat;
    bool sold;
    
    ShowTickets(){
        string row, seat;
        
        Row = row;
        Seat = seat;
        sold = false;
        
    }
    
    bool is_sold(string row, string seat){
        return sold;
    }
    void sell_seat(string row, string seat){
        sold = true;
    }
    string print_ticket(string row, string seat){
        string k = row +" "+seat +" ";
        if (is_sold(row, seat) == 1)
            k+="sold";
        else k+="Available";
        return k;
    }
};

int main () {
  ShowTickets myticket;
  if(!myticket.is_sold("AA","101"))
    myticket.sell_seat ("AA","101");
  cout << myticket.print_ticket("AA","101") << endl;
  cout << myticket.print_ticket("AA","102") << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sell_seat` makes `sold=true` so from that point on `is_sold` returns true. The computer is doing what you told it to do - what were you expecting?

Comment: but only ("AA","101") went through sell_seat, not ("AA","102"), so they should at least have different results?

Comment: Did you tell the computer to care about whether it was ("AA","101") or ("AA","102")?

Comment: Can you please shine some lights on how to do it? or maybe a link to show how to do this will work... thanks a lot

Comment: What have you been learning about in class?

Comment: I feel like it's a crush course on oop. The prof talked about all the theories (abstraction, polymorphism, inheritance etc)  but no coding demonstration. Only some pseudo code. I understood more through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN0x9eZLix4, but didnt find the answer for this lab....

Comment: Okay well OOP is not magic, it's just a different way to arrange the same code, you still have to actually write the code. You have to make a program that remembers which rows and seats were sold. The compiler doesn't do it for you

Comment: If I add row and seat in the constructor, the main function would throw an error since it called (ShowTickets myticket;). The main function is given in the lab so i cant modify that part...

Comment: If I understood what you meant correctly...

Comment: Would you be able to write the program without OOP?

Answer (score 0):

Your data setup is incomplete - "ShowTickets" is supposed to represent up to 10 tickets, but the fields you setup in it can only represent a single ticket.

There are a number of ways you could setup the data - you could turn rows, seats and sold into parallel arrays each of capacity 10, you could do a map<string, map<string, bool>> rowsToSeatsToSoldStatus, you could create a singular "ShowTicket" class with row/seat/sold fields and have "ShowTickets" have a vector (or a ShowTicket array field) - focus on setting up the data in a way that makes sense, then you can work on setting up the functions to read or write said data appropriately.